# What are all of the available zoomus.conf options?

Tags: zoom-meeting

Zoom for Linux uses `~/.config/zoomus.conf` to set certain zoom properties, but I am looking to disable the "auto adjust mic volume" feature.

Is there documentation for all of the available `zoomus.conf` options that I can set?

Comment: "Zoom Linux" isn't a supported Ubuntu release, and isn't supported on AskUbuntu.

Comment: OP: What is "zoom linux"? Is it an OS? Are you just using Zoom on Ubuntu?

Comment: Zoom, as in [Zoom](https://zoom.us/), the massively popular-in-the-pandemic video conferencing platform… Where've you guys been?

Comment: @Oli Sorry, I've been hiding under a rock for a while. Ha ha.

Answer (score 5):

This is the most complete listing that I've been able to assemble from about 570 installations across my employer's network:

```
[General]
GeoLocale=system
SensitiveInfoMaskOn=true                    (false|true)
asBarTopMargin=30                           (18~)
autoPlayGif=false                           (false|true)
autoScale=false                             (false|true)
bForceMaximizeWM=false                      (false|true)
blockUntrustedSSLCert=false                 (false|true)
captureHDCamera=true                        (false|true)
chatListPanelLastWidth=230                  (100~)
conf.webserver=https://zoom.us
currentMeetingId=
deviceID=
enable.host.auto.grab=true                  (false|true)
enableAlphaBuffer=true                      (false|true)
enableCloudSwitch=false                     (false|true)
enableLog=true                              (false|true)
enableMiniWindow=true                       (false|true)
enableQmlCache=true                         (false|true)
enableScreenSaveGuard=false                 (false|true)
enableStartMeetingWithRoomSystem=false      (false|true)
enableTestMode=false                        (false|true)
enableWaylandShare=false                    (false|true)
fake.version=
flashChatTime=0                             (0~10)
forceEnableTrayIcon=true                    (false|true)
forceSSOURL=
host.auto.grab.interval=10                  (5~60)
isTransCoding=false                         (false|true)
logLevel=info                               (info|warn|none)
newMeetingWithVideo=true                    (false|true)
playSoundForNewMessage=false                (false|true)
scaleFactor=1                               (0.25~4.00)
sso_domain=.zoom.us
sso_gov_domain=.zoomgov.com
system.audio.type=default                   (default|alsa)
upcoming_meeting_header_image=
useSystemTheme=false                        (false|true)
userEmailAddress=

[AS]
showframewindow=true                        (false|true)

[Proxy]
httpProxyHost=
httpProxyPort=
httpsProxyHost=
httpsProxyPort=
pacFilePath=http://wpad.my.company.com/wpad.dat
proxyType=pacfile

[CodeSnippet]
lastCodeType=0
wrapMode=0

[chat.recent]
recentlast.session=

[zoom_new_im]
is_landscape_mode=false
main_frame_pixel_pos_narrow="376,680"
main_frame_pixel_pos_wide="810,680"
```

I've never seen any documentation explaining valid values for most of these items, unfortunately, but have written known options in the brackets. There is no specific option for the auto volume feature to the best of my knowledge, but perhaps you can change `system.audio.type` from `default` to `alsa` and control it with the standard audio settings.

Comment: I've tried entering different variables from this list (like changing the sso domain) but didn't see any immediate effect. Is there a command I need to run after editing the config file? Do I need to reboot the machine?

Comment: You will need to restart Zoom itself, but not the entire computer.

Comment: I couldn't seem to get it working. Is there an example config file you can provide and which directory I need to place it into?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, the mac settings are the same.
These settings are indirectly documented here: https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115001799006-Mass-deploying-preconfigured-settings-for-Mac.
In some cases when the property starts with. "z", remove the "z"

the specific property that I was looking for is this one:

```
AudioAutoAdjust=false
```