# How to apply custom Zoom configs on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, zoom-meeting

I found a [similar post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1388053/785799) asking about which config options are available. It didn't  explicitly mention how to apply the configs and I couldn't seem to figure it out.

I'm trying to install Zoom on many computers with preconfigured settings. It would use a config file with the different preconfigured settings.

I tried creating a config file in `~/.config/zoomus.conf` using a few different formats but none of them seemed to do anything.

These are the primary configs I'm trying to apply.

```
[General]
FullScreenWhenJoin=1
DisableVirtualBkgnd=1
DisableVideoFilters=1
nogoogle=1
nofacebook=1
nosso=1
login_domain=domain.com
zDisableLocalRecord=1
DisableRemoteControl=1
```

I would like to be able to apply any of the configs that Zoom has available.

---

I found official Zoom documentation for implementing these configurations on [Windows](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362163-Mass-deploying-with-preconfigured-settings-for-Windows) and [macOS](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115001799006-Mass-deploying-preconfigured-settings-for-Mac), I found no documentation on applying them in Ubuntu (or Linux at all).

If there are any other workarounds or solutions anybody knows about, I'm open to trying it out.

Comment: 1. remove the `z` from in front of whatever settings have one 2. the settings need to be under a proper heading, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1388088/1083397

Comment: @Esther I tried applying just a single setting from the answer (`sso_domain=.domain.com`) with the `[General]` header and even that didn't work...